# Find The Longest Consecutive Subsequence Of Distinct Items In A Sequence

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, data-stream

How do you find the longest row of different(!) elements in an array?

We have a matrix
Our task is to find a row in this matrix where is the longest row of different elements

For example
0 1 2 3 4 1 2 3
Should count 0 1 2 3 4 = 5 elements

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do. Show at least an example.

Comment: Perfect example of how NOT to ask a question on stackoverflow

Comment: you'll need to define the problem in more explicit terms. what should we do if there are 2 sequences of the same length?

Comment: Count the length of the row, sort it, remove one from the count every-time an element is the same as the last element was. The count that remains is the unique element count. Rinse and repeat for all rows.

Answer (score 6):

Try to use Kadane's algorithm described here: [Maximum Subarray Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem)

Just replace sum operation with adding-to-set and find-in-set operations. So, you is able to create a O(n) algo.

This is my try:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int mas[] = {1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,2};
    size_t count = sizeof(mas)/sizeof(mas[0]);

    size_t best = 0;
    int best_index = 0;
    unordered_set<int> unique;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        while (unique.find(mas[i]) != unique.end()) {
            unique.erase(mas[i - unique.size()]);
        }
        unique.insert(mas[i]);
        if (unique.size() > best) {
            best = unique.size();
            best_index = i - best + 1;
        }
    }

    cout << "Index = " << best_index << " Length = " << best << endl;
}
```

Gives output:

```
Index = 3 Length = 4
```

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you use two data structures:

- a `std::list` of integers
- a `std::unordered_map` mapping integers into iterators of the list

Now operate as follows. When you encounter the next integer, check if it is in the unordered map.

- If it is, find the corresponding iterator in the list, and remove it and all items left of it (from both list and unordered map)
- If it is not, add it to the list, and set the unordered map to point at it

Furthermore, at each step, track both the step index, and the size of the unordered map (or the list). Output the index of the largest size, at the end.

This algorithm is [amortized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortized_analysis) expected linear time: although there might be a step that removes more than a single list item (from each of the data structures), each item enters and leaves them at most once.

---

**Example**

Here is an example of the two data structures at some step. The grey map references items in the blue linked list.

[image]

The distinct length is now 4. If 2 is now encountered, however, then it and the link(s) left of it (in this case 3) will be purged before it is added, and the length will be reduced to 3.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
  const int len = 4;
  int arr[len][len] = {{1, 2, 2, 2}, {3, 2, 3, 5}, {2, 4, 3, 6}, {1, 1, 1, 1}};
  int max = -1, current = 1;
  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j < len; j++) {
      if (arr[i][j] != arr[i][j - 1]) {
        current++;
      } else {
        if (current > max) {
          max = current;
        }
        current = 1;
      }
    }
    if (current > max) {
      max = current;
    }
    current = 1;
  }
  // output max
```

It is not very elegant solution, but it works

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in O(n) using a caterpillar algorithm.

- Head and Tail pointers begin in the same spot. You move the head along and add to a hash set if it isn't already there.
- If the head can't move, move the tail. Remove the corresponding number from the hash set.
- As you're going along, see if there's a new max length.
- The head and tail are each at each location once, so it's O(n)